# For Loop in R - deleting all rows which match by one variable

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to completely delete rows in a dataset for cases with matching variables (case ID) with the help of this function I wrote:

```
del_row_func <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(x$FALL_ID)){
   for(j in 1:length(x$FALL_ID)){
     if(x$FALL_ID[i] == x$FALL_ID[j] & i != j){
       x[-i, ]
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Anybody have an idea, why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code didn't work was that you weren't modifying or returning `x`. However, there is a better way to remove all rows with a duplicated ID:

```
dat = data.frame(FALL_ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3), y = 1:4)
dat
#   FALL_ID y
# 1       1 1
# 2       2 2
# 3       2 3
# 4       3 4
dat[!duplicated(dat$FALL_ID) & !duplicated(dat$FALL_ID, fromLast=T),]
#   FALL_ID y
# 1       1 1
# 4       3 4
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it asap. But still, how would I do it with the for loop?

Comment: I guess you could replace `x[-i,]` with `x <- x[-i,]` and add `return(x)` at the end. Still this is not a good idea -- it is quite inefficient. Typically tasks that you would use a `for` loop for in other programming languages should be solved differently in R.

Comment: Actually, I don't even think that code will work, because the row indexing will become different once you remove a row. The code I posted identifies all the rows that are not duplicates with `!duplicated(dat$FALL_ID) & !duplicated(dat$FALL_ID, fromLast=T)` and returns only those rows. By subsetting only once, we don't have to deal with row indices changing anymore, and we get the added benefit of it being much more efficient.